# Text outside parameters section in sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, sphinx-napoleon

I am writing documentation for my function using napoleon syntax. I would like to have a paragraph after my parameter list in the docs. The docs currently look like this:

```
def x(a):
    """
    A sample function.

    A sample blurb before.

    Parameters
    ==========
    a : str
        The input parameter

    A paragraph after.
    """
    return a
```

The docs are currently rendered (using the RTD theme) as

> **`x`**`(`*`a`*`)`
>
> A sample function.
>
> A sample blurb before.
>
> **Parameters**          * **a**(*str*) - The input parameter
>                                 *
>   **paragraph after**(*A*) -

What I would like to see is

> **`x`**`(`*`a`*`)`
>
> A sample function.
>
> A sample blurb before.
>
> **Parameters**          * **a**(*str*) - The input parameter
>
> A paragraph after.

How do I tell sphinx/napoleon/rST to break out of the `Parameters` section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that what I have in the `Parameters` [section](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#sections) is a [definition list](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#definition-lists). To mark the end of the list, two blank lines are necessary to avoid confusion, since reST allows for blank lines in a definition list:

```
def x(a):
    """
    A sample function.

    A sample blurb before.

    Parameters
    ==========
    a : str
        The input parameter


    A paragraph after.
    """
    return a
```